# Squarefree Palindromes

Tags: code-golf, sequence, palindrome, factoring

Create the shortest function, program, or expression that calculates a sequence of squarefree palindromic numbers.

A squarefree number is one which is not evenly divisible by a square number (i.e. does not contain a repeated prime factor). For example, \$44 = 2^2 \times 11\$ is not squarefree, whereas \$66 = 2\times3\times11\$ is.

You can find a list of the numbers from this [link](https://oeis.org/A071251). The list goes as such: `1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 22, 33, 55, 66, 77, 101, 111, 131, 141, 151, 161, 181, 191...`

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I would suggest adding a scoring criterion to your question (you've tagged it code-golf, but it's still nice to have it said explicitly). Also, input/output rules are a bit unclear, so you might want to look at some other questions and update your question based on that. It's recommended to use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) before posting questions, so you can get feedback on challenges.

Comment: @user The challenge does say _Create the shortest function, program, or expression_. An expression is not a [standard format for code-golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/58563), however.

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, you're right, that's the first line! I was looking for something like "Scoring: The program/function with the least number of bytes wins"

Comment: Am I missing something in the terminology here?  If it's a prime factorization, all the factors must be primes.  Thus, none of them can be a square.  I think I understand what's being sought here (no two identical prime factors), but it should be stated explicitly.

Comment: @Xcali Given the absence of 121 from the sequence, I think the palindrome shouldn't be a factor of some prime squared?

Comment: @user, then the question is different: What palendromic numbers are not perfect squares?

Comment: "which do not have a square in their prime factorization", I think it's pretty clear. By prime factorization, they mean 22=2*11, and 44=(2*2)*11 -- so 44 can be factored into the product of a square and another number. I edited the question so it's a bit clearer.

Comment: I've edited the question slightly to include the definition of a squarefree number, as well as examples. However, until you define "calculates a sequence of", this is still unclear. I'd recommend going by our [standard sequence rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info)

Comment: I'm not clear, does the sequence need to list every squarefree palindrome, or just be any infinite sequence of such numbers, presumably distinct?

Comment: Since there are some clarity concerns here I am going to close this question to prevent further answers until this is sorted out.  This is a temporary mesures and as the clarity points have been addressed it can be reopened by myself or other users.

Comment: To recap: The main points that I see as unclear are 1) What is an expression? 2) What input does a function take? and more generally what sort of io is required? (You can defer to the site's standards for a good deal of this) 3) Does the sequence need to list *every* squarefree palindrome or just be a sequence of them?

Comment: A link to OEIS is provided in the question. I don't think it's ambiguous. You're probably just nitpicking at language inaccuracies.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>82</s> 75 bytes

```python
n=0
while 1:
 n+=1
 if`n`[::-1]==`n`*all(n%i**2for i in range(2,n)):print n
```

[**Try it Online!**](https://tio.run/##Fc3RCoIwGIbhc6/igwjUEtTDxbqITiNw0cyf5rcxV9LVLzt7n6M3fNPk2edM3RbrJM6iUwV40F0BGQcOV6Wa7qb1lrVxruRe6roffYRAiGj4tGV/ZFWpEIUJzDtc7Ow/FmmSBU5oYfjYZBGif0YzYxXnEN8EPZsl@fC/gee@bdU9WvM65R8)

If this was a decision problem (54 bytes):

```python
lambda n:`n`[::-1]==`n`*all(n%i**2for i in range(2,n))
```

#### Explanation:

```python
`n`[::-1]==`n`                     # If n is a palindrome. `n` is repr(n).
                                   # We check that it's the same
                                   # backwards and forwards.
              *                    # Multiplplying 2 booleans is AND
all(n%i**2for i in range(2,n))     # Check that squares of all #'s < n do not divide n
```

Comment: Your condition can be shortened to `\`n\`[::-1]==\`n\`*all(n%i**2for i in range(2,n))`.

Comment: @ovs Nice one! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

Generates the sequence

```
ḋ≠&↔?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KGsOKCgeG2oOKGljEwMP/huIviiaAm4oaUP////1o)

```
ḋ≠&↔? (the input's)
ḋ     prime decomposition
 ≠    has only unique elements
  &   and the input
   ↔  reversed
    ? is the input
      (and also the output)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
foS=upİ↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py0/2La04MiGR21T/v8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>81</s>  76 bytes

Returns the n-th term, 1-indexed.

```javascript
f=(n,i)=>(g=d=>i[d]&&i[d]-i[k++]?1:i%d--**2?g(d):d)(i+=k='')||n--?f(n,-~i):i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBDoIwEADvvGIPCF1qjegNXHgIIYFQICukNWC8AH691stkDpN5tp927RZ@vZWxunduIGHOjFSIkTQVXOk6iv5UXE1S1mWa8UkrlSS3chQaM42CJU0Ux7jvRqly8AP1ZczYDXYRBgjSHAw8CO5XL1IibAFAZ81q5/4y21E0rQg3c6Bvw80P8GgwDw73Aw)

### Commented

#### Helper function

The helper function **g** checks simultaneously whether **i** is palindromic and squarefree. The variable **d** is used as a counter to test the divisors and as a decreasing digit index. The variable **k** is used as an increasing digit index. Both **i** and **k** are defined in the wrapper.

```javascript
g = d =>            // g is a recursive function taking a counter d
  i[d] &&           //   if i[d] is defined
  i[d] - i[k++] ?   //   and it's not equal to i[k] (increment k afterwards):
    1               //     i is not palindromic: force a truthy result
  :                 //   else:
    i % d-- ** 2 ?  //     if d² is not a divisor of i (decrement d afterwards):
      g(d)          //       do a recursive call
    :               //     else:
      d             //       return d (0 if i is squarefree)
```

#### Wrapper

The main function decrements **n** whenever **g** returns **0** and stops when **n = 0**.

```javascript
f = (n, i) =>       // f is a recursive function taking an index n
  g(i += k = '') || //   set k to a zero'ish empty string,
                    //   coerce i to a string
                    //   and invoke g with d = i
  n-- ?             //   if the above call was truthy or n is not equal to 0:
    f(n, -~i)       //     do a recursive call with i + 1
  :                 //   else:
    i               //     success: return i
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 52 bytes

```
Do[If[SquareFreeQ@n&&PalindromeQ@n,Print@n],{n,∞}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98lP9ozLTq4sDSxKNWtKDU10CFPTS0gMSczL6UoPxfE1QkoyswrcciL1anO03nUMa829v///wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
1ÆfQƑ×ŒḂƲ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//McOGZlHGkcOXxZLhuILGsiP//zIw)

Returns the first `n` squarefree palindromes

### How it works

```
1ÆfQƑ×ŒḂƲ# - Main link. Takes no arguments
        Ʋ  - Group the previous 4 links into a monad f(k):
 Æf        -   Prime factorisation of k (with repeats)
    Ƒ      -   Is this invariant under:
   Q       -     Deduplication
      ŒḂ   -   Is k a palindrome?
     ×     -   Both conditions are true?
1        # - Read an integer n from STDIN. Count up k = 1, 2, 3, ...
             until n such k return true under f(k). Return those k
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Prints the infinite sequence.

```
∞ʒÂQyÓà*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5MONwVWHp58eIHW//8A)

**Commented**:

```python
∞        # push the list of natural numbers [1, 2, ...]
 ʒ       # keep the values for which the following is 1:
  Â      #   push the number and its reverse
   Q     #   are both equal?
    y    #   push the number again
     Ó   #   push the exponents of the prime factorisation
      à  #   take the maximum
       * #   multiply both numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=all`, 52 bytes

```perl
$_-$r||(all{$r%$_**2}2..$_)&&say while$r=reverse++$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzRCoJAEAB/ZaFNSlFU6MXwA4Kil3o@jtjw6PTkdi@J7Ne77GlgYGYkb3cR57bar3QQd7eBOxAHvX4QcPAEE8FND8BEIB2BCzIGgamjAS6HM4jpif82osrRz/NGW/tGv0aVpvWnLgpU2yRh/VoaYwl96@lJninLUMX4daMYN3DMT7uirMqFR8PSNFcxtl1ePw)